# SIM808 AT+CIPSEND strange behaviour

Tags: gprs

I set the SIM808 module in single connection (CIPMUX=0) set it to connect to the GPRS network and everything works fine. The problem arises when I try to write messages. I have to transfer binary data so I used the length parameter of CIPSEND:
I would expect a situation as:

```
--> At+CIPSEND=70
<-- > 
--> { 70 bytes message}
<-- SEND OK
```

so the SIM808 should send my data after the 70th is gone but it doesn't happen.  Because apart the 1st time, the SEND OK answer is not detected, seems it doesn't care. I don't understand where is the problem and the SIM808 in this condition is not able to send any data.
Any idea?
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is related to hardware incompatibility between SIM808 and some types of SIM cards. SIMcom assures SIM808 works with every 2G SIM cards, unfortunately they are impossible to buy in Italy at shops but I found the last 4G + NFC cards sold by Vodafone work. The problem is that it is difficult to know what "models" of SIM cards work and what no.